# Ordering JS/CSS load order across multiple xml blocks

Tags: magento2, blocks, xml

When rendered, the below core XML loads the `require.js` file in (for example) **Position 10** in the HTML Source:

`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
    <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
</head>
```

And the following custom XML loads `example.css` file after in **Position 11** of the HTML source:

`app/design/frontend/Vendor/module/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <css src="example/example.css"/>
</head>
```

**Example/Sample HTML Source**

```
 9. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://example.com/pub/static/version1234/frontend/Vendor/module/en_GB/mage/calendar.css">
10. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/pub/static/version1234/frontend/Vendor/module/en_GB/requirejs/require.js"></script>
11. <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://example.com/pub/static/version1234/frontend/Vendor/module/en_GB/example/example.css">
```

**Question**

How do I ensure that my `example.css` file loads before the `requirejs-config.js`?